set fixedHeader datatable yajra
i need add fixed headers to the table create with yajra datatables in laravel 9.28
I have other tables with parameter: ->fixedHeader(true) and when i´m scrolling down, my headers stay in top.
In my new table, i´m setting this parameter:
return $this->builder()
            ->setTableId('web-newspaper-table')
            ->columns($this->getColumns())
            ->minifiedAjax()
            ->orderBy(2, 'DESC')
            ->destroy(true)
            ->fixedHeader(true)
            ->responsive(true)
            ->serverSide(true)
            ->stateSave(true)
            ->processing(true)
            ->pageLength(100)
            ->dom($this->domHtml)
            ->language(__('app.datatable'))
            ->parameters([
                'fixedHeader' => true,
                'initComplete' => 'function () {
                   window.LaravelDataTables["web-newspaper-table"].buttons().container()
                    .appendTo( "#table-actions")
                }',
                'fnDrawCallback' => 'function( oSettings ) {
                    $("body").tooltip({
                        selector: \'[data-toggle="tooltip"]\'
                    })
                }',
            ])
            ->buttons(Button::make(['extend' => 'excel', 'text' => '<i class="fa fa-file-export"></i> ' . trans('app.exportExcel')]));
    }

When i´m doing scrolling down, my headers not set in top.
i trayed to add styles:
#web-newspaper-table thead th {
        position: sticky !important;
        z-index: 12;
        top: 0px;
        background: white;
    }

i trayed to add javascript:
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#web-newspaper-table').DataTable({
                fixedHeader: {
                    header: true,
                    footer: true
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

But always i have same problem. Not keep headers in top.
I read in other forum, that <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css') }}"> this style create conflicts with <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.2/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css"> that, also, i add this style or plugin, and althought not set my headers in top...
What i´m doing bad?
Thanks for readme, and sorry for my bad english

Sorry for problem. Fix header in Yajra Datatables, make sure to include the right CSS and JS files for FixedHeader. Add these in your Blade template:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.9/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.9/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>

Then initialize with:
$('#your-table-id').DataTable({
    fixedHeader: true
});

Yajra Datatables Package Documentation
Maybe this helps?

@anastasio3 finally i resolve my problem with css and jquery. first i created a new class .affix {
top: 13%;
position: fixed !important;
z-index: 9998;
background-color: #000;
}
and before, with jquery controlling scroll event, change my class name into header table
